# I am using a box hover effect ( shadow ) for text and i want the box to fill the the inside and not give a shadow

Tags: css, hover, shadow, effects, fill

i want the code to be for filling i am usin g

```
<style type="text/css"> 
  .box:hover { 
     -moz-box-fill: 0 0 10px ##FF0000; 
     -webkit-box-fill: 0 0 10px ##FF0000; 
     box-shadow: 0 0 30px #FF0000; padding: 2px; 
  } 
</style>
```

for the shadow. any help would be usefull :)

Comment: have you tried: box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px #ff000; ? also, please elaborate you question more by explaining further, "fill" is a bit ambiguous, what do you mean by that? Also, if you could provide both the HTML and CSS (and a fiddle if you may). It would let us help you out more

Comment: i dont want the effect to be a shadow i want the inside of the box to be solid colored. i tried flipping words between shadow and fill but that didnt seem to have worked.

Comment: you probably want to change the background color then? use background: #ff0000; on .box:hover.